# Implementing Shortest Path Algorithm Dijkstra

Tags: python, matrix, graph, operators, graph-theory

Implementing Dijkstra Algorithm on the following graph and getting error on < operator while comparing:

```
        if new_dist < next.get_distance():
```

Error Function:     heapq.heapify(unvisited_queue)

Error:

### Graph data: ( a , b, 7) ( a , c, 9) ( a , f, 14) ( b , a, 7) ( b , c, 10) ( b , d, 15) ( c , a, 9) ( c , b, 10) ( c , d, 11) ( c , f, 2) ( d , b, 15) ( d , c, 11) ( d , e, 6) ( e , d, 6) ( e , f, 9) ( f , a, 14) ( f , c, 2) ( f , e, 9) Dijkstra's shortest path Traceback (most recent call last): File "e:\Graph Theory\DijestraShortestPath.py", line 156, in  dijkstra(g, g.get_vertex('a'), g.get_vertex('e')) File "e:\Graph Theory\DijestraShortestPath.py", line 95, in dijkstra heapq.heapify(unvisited_queue) TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Vertex' and 'Vertex'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We're not mind readers, so it would be better if you showed us your code.

But based purely on the little bit of information you're giving us.  It seems that you're using a "Vertex" as your data structure, and Python does not know how to compare two Vertex structures.

One strong possibility is that you're putting items like (distance, Vertex) in your heap, and expecting the heap to be able to sort them.  But if two objects in the heap have the same distance, (distance, vertex1) and (distance, vertex2) will end up comparing vertex1 and vertex2.

You can either make your vertices have a compare function, or you can keep a counter, and add things to the heap by writing:

```
counter += 1
heapq.heappush(heap, (distance, counter, vertex))
```

so that you are assured the vertices are never compared.